# Populate ListView upon changing combobox - proper MVVM implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, jira-rest-api

**My goal is**: ComboxBox with list of Jira account names and ListView that will display response from query sent to jira upong selecting the user in ComboBox (because account name is the part of the query).

**What I have:** little knowledge of C#, WPF, MVVM and *working solution* (code below), but it's not MVVM in any way. So, I've read a lot of about MVVM (relayCommand, PropertyChanged, etc), but for some reason I just can't come up with the solution on how to refactor this program to MVVM. One of the biggest problem is that I cant figure out how make that request to Jira and result in a form of IQueryable fit the MVVM-pattern. I mean, where should I place it.

**So, please,** if anyone could hint me what should I do generally to convert this program to follow MVVM pattern or any other type of advice, I would be very grateful!

**MainWindow.xamls.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }

private void OnNameComboChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Issues.Clear();

    string name = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;
    Issues fetchedIssues = new Issues();

    var issuesList = fetchedIssues.FetchIssues(name); // returns the list of Issues in a type of --> IQueryable<Issue>
    foreach (var issue in issuesList)
    {
        Issues.Add(issue);
    }    
}

public MainWindow()
{
    Issues = new ObservableCollection<Issue>();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Name="Main_Window" x:Class="Dull.MainWindow"
    ........
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"> <!-- how I link contexts-->
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Name" SelectionChanged="OnNameComboChanged" > <!-- Combox box with nicknames -->
            <ComboBoxItem>name of the user</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>another name of the user</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="issuesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}"> <!-- ListView binded to Issues collection -->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various frameworks like [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921153(v=pandp.40).aspx), [Caliburn Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/), [MVVMLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) and many more which provide the features to write MVVM design pattern application. Few of the features which the mentioned frameworks provides

1. DelegateCommand or RelayCommand
2. ViewModelLocator
3. Container/Module
4. Event Aggregator

These features ease to write the code in MVVM design pattern. However if you don't require all these features and don't want to integrate those then don't worry about it.

Now, all the conversation in this answer is based on that you want to write for your implementation without these frameworks.

You can refer to this blog to write [RelayCommand](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/). You do require `ICommand` implementation if you want to segregate View from ViewModel. These commands of ViewModel can be integrated with View using Blends' Interactivity trigger (refer this [sample](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/how-to-use-interaction-triggers-to-handle-user-initiated-events-in-wpf-mvvm/)).

All above was a pre-work for the solution of your question. Follow the steps

1. **Create a ViewModel**

The below ViewModel depicts what you require:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Issue> issues = new ObservableCollection<Issue>();
    public ObservableCollection<Issue> Issues { get {return issues;} }

    private ObservableCollection<string> users = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Users { get {return users;} }

    private string user;
    public string User 
    {
        get 
        {
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            user = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ICommand userChangedCommand;

    public ICommand UserChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return userChangedCommand ?? (userChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                x =>
                {
                    OnUserChanged();
                }));
        }
    }

    private ICommand loadedCommand;

    public ICommand LoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return loadedCommand?? (loadedCommand= new RelayCommand(
                x =>
                {
                    // Write Code here to populate Users collection.
                }));
        }
    }

    private void OnUserChanged()
    {
        Issues.Clear();

        string name = this.User;
        Issues fetchedIssues = new Issues();

        var issuesList = fetchedIssues.FetchIssues(name); // returns the list of Issues in a type of --> IQueryable<Issue>
        foreach (var issue in issuesList)
        {
            Issues.Add(issue);
        }    
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

**2. View Changes:**

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow x:Name="Main_Window" x:Class="Dull.MainWindow" ........
    >
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
       <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectionChanged="OnNameComboChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding User}" > <!-- Combox box is getting user details from ViewModel -->
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UserChangedCommand}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
       </Controls:WindowCommands>
      </Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="issuesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}"> <!-- ListView binded to Issues collection -->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**3.** Now the last part How to **Bind ViewModel to View**.

If you are using the mentioned frameworks then this would be trivial based on `ViewModelLocator` feature. However, to achieve without the frameworks, you can use one of the below approach.
1) Create the instance ViewModel and assign in the Control's InitializeComponent method (.Xaml.cs)

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();
this.DataContext = vm;
```

However this breaks the pure MVVM design pattern

2) You can create the instance in View itself

```
   <Controls:MetroWindow x:Name="Main_Window" x:Class="Dull.MainWindow">
       <Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
        <VM:MyViewModel />
    </Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    ...............
   </Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I think I've understood the layout and how it works! If you would there is one more question: when I change user in comboBox, issues in ListView get added, so I had to Issues.Clear() so issues assigned to new selected user only will be dispayed. Could you please explain, is this how it should be done with MVVM or its dirty hack? I mean is it acceptable or I'm missing something?

Comment: That' the right way. If you see I've not defined the setter for Issues collection as it sometime it's being misused (can discuss about later). So to populate the Issues collection, let's first Clear all the items in it and populate it for the selected user.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, you're really helping me out here :) Sorry if it's too much, but I've got another question: given my case, where I get IQueryable<Issue> from another party, so it's not mine class and so forth, is it possible if I want not just to display information about Issue in ListView (by binding properties of that class), but also some conditional displaying in that ListView based on some properties in each Issue? I mean if for-example Issue.Type = Open, then I want to display icon in that particular ListViewItem that corresponds to that Issue with Type=Open? Gosh, nvm, too much text

Comment: Yes, It's possible. You have already defined the `ItemTemplate` so use to display the element based on your logic and data.